# Running an android emulator on xamarin visual studio 2019 shows transparent screen

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2019

[it popsup like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCQpS.jpg)

Running an android emulator on xamarin visual studio 2019 shows transparent screen

Comment: sry for my poor english.

Comment: Have you checked the settings of this emulator through three dots at bottom ? Maybe you can find something there.
Also,please add more info like Version of Xamarin,VS

Comment: --> Found Xamarin.Android 10.0.6.2 it's say like this

i run on
-windows 10 Home
-visual studio 2019